# Ideals of Laurent polynomial ring over matrix ring

Tags: matrices, noncommutative-rings, ideals

Let $K$ be a field. Let $R=M_2(K)\langle x,x^{-1}\rangle$ be the ring obtained from the matrix ring $M_2(K)$ by adjoining two elements $x$ and $x^{-1}$ which are inverse to each other ($x$ and $x^{-1}$ are not supposed to commute with the elements of $M_2(K)$). What is known about the ideal structure of $R$? Is there a classification of the ideals of $R$ available?